# Downtime of volume backed live migration between two compute nodes (different version: liberty-mitaka) is too high

Tags: migration, upgrade, openstack

I'm working on upgrading OpenStack from Liberty to Mitaka. I've upgraded my controller to mitaka. Mitaka controller will manage liberty computes and mitaka computes. After that I do live migration VMs from liberty compute to mitaka compute. when live migrate between two computes different version, I recognized downtime was too high (30 ICMP packets loss with 200ms interval) than two computes same version (5 ICMP packets loss with 200ms interval), summary:

- live-migration between liberty-liberty computes: 5 ICMP packets loss with 200ms interval
- live-migration between liberty-mitaka computes: 30 ICMP packets loss with 200ms interval

I don't know why it happened

My ENV:

- 1 controller mitaka
- 2 compute liberty
- 1 compute mitaka
- OVS ML2 plugin with DVR
- Ceph Backend Storage

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Issue is not related to openstack version.

The following variables may affect live migration speed:

1. The number of modified pages on the virtual machine to be migrated—the
   larger the number of modified pages, the longer the virtual machine will   remain in a migrating state.
2. Available network bandwidth between source and destination servers.
3. Hardware configuration of source and destination servers.
4. Load on source and destination servers.
5. Available bandwidth between servers and shared storage.

Comment: Hi @suraj, I make sure my instance has no load and network bandwidth still has more when I live migration